# Adding headers in karate.config () throws unnamed exception,but works from feature file

Tags: karate

What works

Include a header in a feature file

Background:

```
* configure headers = {x-nv-test-header: '123'}
```

What doesn't work

In config.js
karate.configure('headers',{ x-nv-test-header: '123'} )

It throws me an error at
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: SyntaxError: Unnamed:12:35 Expected : but found -
karate.configure('headers',{ x-nv-test-header: '123'} )
^
Unnamed:12:93 Expected ; but found )
karate.configure('headers',{ x-nv-test-header: '123'} )

Comment: I think I figured it out, Use as below

karate.configure('headers',{' x-nv-test-header': '123'} )